# how to understand time complexity from a plot?

Tags: plot, time-complexity, big-o

I have written a program in C where I allocate memory to store a matrix of dimensions *n-by-n* and then feed a linear algebra subroutine with. I'm having big troubles in understanding how to identify time complexity for these operations from a plot. Particularly, I'm interested in identify how CPU time scales as a function of *n*, where *n* is my size.

To do so, I created an array of n = 2, 4, 8, ..., 512 and I computed the CPU time for both the operations. I repeated this process 10000 times for each *n* and I took the mean eventually. I therefore come up with a second array that I can match with my array of n.

I've been suggested to print in double logarithmic plot, and I read [here](http://www.intmath.com/exponential-logarithmic-functions/7-graphs-log-semilog.php) and [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogPlot.html) that, using this way, *"powers shows up as a straight line"* ([2](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogPlot.html)). This is the resulting figure (*dgesv* is the linear algebra subroutine I used).

[image: double logarithmic plot]

Now, I'm guessing that my time complexity is *O(log n)* since I get straight lines for both my operations (I do **not** take into consideration the red line). I saw the shapes differences between, say, linear complexity, logarithmic complexity etc. But I still have doubts if I should say something about the time complexity of *dgesv*, for instance. I'm sure there's a way that I don't know at all, so I'd be glad if someone could help me in *understanding how to look at this plot properly*.

**PS: if there's a specific community where to post this question, please let me know so I could move it avoiding much more mess here. Thanks everyone.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your yellow line, it appears to be going from (0.9, -2.6) to (2.7, 1.6), giving it a slope roughly equal to 2.5. As you're plotting log(t) versus log(n) this means that:

```
log(t) = 2.5 log(n) + c
```

or, exponentiating both sides:

```
t = exp(2.5 log(n) + c) = c' n^2.5
```

The power of 2.5 may be an underestimate as your [`dsegv`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512.html#ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512) likely [has a cost](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node71.html#standardflopcount) of 2/3 n^3 (though O(n^2.5) is [theoretically possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Theoretical_complexity)).

Comment: that is really helpful, thanks! May I ask what the `c` stands for?

Comment: Some constant (you could calculate it as c = -2.6 - 2.5 * .9, and then c' = e^c, but that depends on the logarithm base and the unit scales that you choose).